# ユーザーを日本語で検索できない

Tags: バグ, 完了

ユーザーを検索するときは[検索するユーザーを入力:]テキストボックスにキーワードを入力して検索しますが、
日本語では検索することができませんでした。

例えば"田中"というキーワードで検索しても、
ユーザーの表示には変化がありません。

もしも該当するユーザーが存在しないのであっても、
"検索に一致するユーザーはありません。"と表示されるかと思います。

Comment: 私もユーザー名が日本語の人を数人検索してみたのですが、同じ結果でした。これは日本語対応のバグのように思えます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ほとんどのユーザー名は日本語ではありませんので、あるユーザーを検索しました：

[image: パンダパジャマ]

「パンダ」を検索しますと、ちゃんと探せます。探せないユーザー名があったら、そのユーザー名と検索された文書を教えてください。

Comment: コメントで少し自分のミスがありました、尾崎隆大さんを検索する時に、「尾崎隆大」と入力すると出てくるのですが、「尾崎」とだけ入力すると出てきません。 自分の場合をまとめると、漢字の日本語ユーザーのフルネームだと出てくるが、名前の一部では出てこないということです。

Comment: 「パン」では探せず、「パンダ」では探せることを確認しました。2文字までは検索が開始されないようです。日本人は2文字の苗字が多いので、「田中」のような検索ではうまくいかないように感じてしまうのかもしれません。

Comment: @rizaudo なるほど、バグを登録します。

Comment: @BladeanMericle なるほど！複雑そうな問題です。開発者と相談します。

Comment: @jmac Bladeanさんの話を聞いて、テストしてみました。やはり2文字までの文字列だと検索されないようです。 例えば、「尾崎」では検索が出来ないのですが、「尾崎隆」では検索が出来ます。